# Из записи RGB значения цветов записать в отдельные ячейки

Tags: excel, office, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно перенести числа с помощью функции лефт и райт в соответствующее ячейки, при этом чтобы не было запятых. И как вынести число для колонки "ГРИН"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Красный:

```
=--ЛЕВБ(C2;ПОИСК(",";C2)-1)
```

Зеленый:

```
=--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПСТР(C2;ДЛСТР(D2)+3;3);",";)
```

Синий:

```
=--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПРАВБ(C2;3);",";)
```

Двойное отрицание преобразует текстовую запись число в число.

Можно одной формулой для трех цветов:

```
=--ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(","&$C2;",";ПОВТОР(" ";99));СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)*99;99)
```